# Prove a map is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X=(-3/2,-1/2]\times S^1 \cup [1/2,3/2)\times S^1 \longrightarrow (-1,1)\times S^1$ be a map given by:
$$f(t,x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
(t+1/2,\varphi(x)) & & t<0 \\
(t-1/2,x) & & t>0
\end{array}\right.$$
and $\varphi:S^1\longrightarrow S^1$ is a homeomorphism (not trivial).
I want to prove that $f$ is closed (or open, I think it should be both open and closed).

I take $P$ a closed set in $X$.

- If $P$ is closed and it is contained in a subset of the form $[a,-1/2]\times S^1 \cup [1/2,b]\times S^1$ for some $a\in(-3/2,-1/2)$, $b\in(1/2,3/2)$ then I take the restriction to that set and use $P$ is closed on $[a,-1/2]\times S^1 \cup [1/2,b]\times S^1$, which is compact son $P$ is compact...
- If $P$ is not contained in any subset like that (example: $P=(-3/2,-1]\times S^1$), how do I proceed?

Comment: I don't think the map is open.  For example, $(-3/2,-1/2] \times S^1$ is open in $X$, but its image is $(-1,0] \times S^1$, which isn't open in the codomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $f$ factors through some suited homeomorphism (looking like $f$, involving $φ$ etc.)
$$((-3/2..-1/2] × S^1) ∪ ([1/2..3/2) × S^1) → ((-1..0] × S^1) \sqcup ([0..1) × S^1),$$
and the map
$$((-1..0] × S^1) \sqcup ([0..1) × S^1) → (-1..1) × S^1,~(x,t) ↦ (x,t),$$
so it suffices to show that the latter is closed.  This step just reduces the clutter.

Now, both maps
$$(-1..0] × S^1 → (-1..1) × S^1\quad\text{and}\quad [0..1) × S^1 → (-1..1) × S^1$$
are inclusions of closed subspaces, hence are closed maps.  This already suffices.

More generally, for spaces $X$, $Y$ and continuous closed maps $f\colon X  → Z$, $g\colon Y → Z$, the map $f \sqcup g \colon X \sqcup Y → Z$ is closed as well, which is easily proven.